# Control the color of individual start menu tiles

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10, the start menu tiles all have the same background color, determined by the color theme you choose.

However, the Microsoft Office tiles (e.g. Excel, Word) each have different colors - Word is blue, Excel is green, etc.

Is there any way to set individual colors on other tiles? E.g. could I set Visual Studio to be purple and Evernote to be green?

To be clear, I don't want to control the overall theme - e.g. I don't want all tiles to be green instead of grey - I want to control the tile colors individually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is help on changing tiles that are shortcuts to exe files here:

[[Tip] Customize Start Screen Tiles Background Color, Text Color and Logo in Windows 8.1 and Later](http://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-start-screen-tiles-background-color-text-color-and-logo-in-windows-8-1/)

and there are some utilities that do it for you.  Here's one:

[Windows Tile Color Changer](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tile-color-changer-download)

It would be nice if this was built in.

Comment: Great - thanks very much!  The Windows Tile Color Changer works well, although it's a pain that the list of applications isn't in alphabetical order - takes ages to find what you're looking for in the list.

Comment: The Windows Tile Color Changer has a virus according to VirusTotal.com - I narrowed it down to one file: MetroFramework.dll v1.3.0. When I downloaded the same exact file from NuGet and unzipped it, that version did not have the virus. - https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroFramework-1.3.0.0/

Answer (score 10):

**[For Desktop Apps](https://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-start-screen-tiles-background-color-text-color-and-logo-in-windows-8-1/)**:

1. Locate the `.exe` for the tile
   a. Right click the *tile* icon, and select "Open File Location"
   b. *Then* right click the *shortcut* icon, and select "Open File Location" *again*
2. Create a new file named `EXE_Name.VisualElementsManifest.xml` and add the following contents:

   ```xml
   <Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <VisualElements BackgroundColor="#666666"
                       ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo="on"
                       ForegroundText="light"/>
   </Application>
   ```
3. Rename the shortcut to refresh the image cache

The previous technique doesn't seem to work on Windows Store / Universal apps, but I can't find anything that does.

Comment: Renaming the shortcut is subject to cause it to be unpinned. If you just toggle the Windows State (i.e. *Run* drop-down: Normal | Minimized | Maximized), or change something in the *Comment* field, then it will refresh (make sure to hit Apply).

Comment: For application running in compatibility mode, it still works but you have to locate the executable yourself because step 1b does lead to it.

Comment: Note that removing `BackgroundColor` will revert the tile to the default theme background color.

Comment: FYI as of the 21H1 release this year, the BackgroundColor seems to be completely ignored on the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a black tile on my desktop, and couldn't change the color.  After countless efforts, I decided to unpin it. Then I proceeded to re-pin the app. This time it came up a beautiful blue color!

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to change all tiles to a color that matches your menu background color.

This is easy an way to fix things if your biggest concern is wanting the color of the app's icon to stand out so that your eyes find the app the faster.

Right click on your desktop background and select 'Personalize'.

In the left column, click 'Colors'.

In the right pane under Choose your color select whatever you want the menu background color to be.  I chose 'dark'.

Just below that is 'Choose your accent color'.  Pick a color very similar or the same as the color you just chose above.  I chose a very dark gray so that the tiles will just be visible against the menu background.

That's it!  Now, for example, when you're looking for your Evernote app which has a green and white icon, the tile behind it will blend in with the menu and your eyes will find the green and white much more quickly.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's goal. He wants to control each tile's color seperately.